# how can i ask a question about myths in skeptics?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

can i ask questions about myths here?

consider this **example**

suppose i am asking about **ghost hunting machines** ,there will be **myths and obviously research papers will be present,**

how can i ask a question regarding **myths** and their source of myth?

why can't we add `myth` tag for future queries?

Comment: history.se may be a good place if you want the source of a myth

Answer (score 2):

By tagging something as a myth you are stating from the outset that it's untrue, which doesn't seem like a very skeptical thing to do. Weather or not something is a myth should be shown by the answer and not from the question.

This site is also not the place for discovering the historical origin of beliefs, only how valid it is to hold certain (on topic) beliefs.

That said I did write an answer to a question along this lines (a long time ago, the sites rules might've changed and this question might be off-topic now, it's also missing a reference to to show it's notable): [Does the idea of vampires come from rabies?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/does-the-idea-of-vampires-come-from-rabies)

However note that the user has a very specific question (on-topic):

> Does the idea of vampires come from rabies?

Rather than the open ended (off-topic):

> Where does the idea of vampires come from?

Comment: Whether is correct.

Comment: @SnackExchange Did you just correct a type that is 10+ years old. lol?

Comment: typo is correct :)